# GVim operator pending commands only work after suspend or waiting an arbitrary amount of time

Tags: vim

Basically, on a fresh boot, many of the standard operator pending commands don't act as they should.

Instead, they seem to act as if the operator pending command was never issued, sort of. `ciw` will sometimes act like `iw` or `iiw`, and I've yet to discover a pattern.

`c`, `d`, `y` (maybe more) won't work, but `f` will. If I suspend the machine and resume, sometimes once, sometimes several times, eventually normal function returns and appears to remain until reboot. Sometimes just leaving it running awhile (an hour or more) seems to do the trick.

Running vim from the terminal, I experience no such issue.

I've tried several packages from Ubuntu, all act the same. I purged vim completely and installed from the gitHub source, zero plugins or .vimrc config, still the same.

Vim shows no mapping that appears relevant, and none at all with `-u NONE`, but if I record a macro or output verbose to file, I see what appears to be vim's internal sequences.

Actual input `qtc^]q` then `"tp` outputs

`<80><fd>b<80><fd>ac<80><fd>b<80><fd>a^]<80><fd>b<80><fd>a`

whereas ordinarily the output would be `c^]`.

I suspend one or more times, and I can get back to work.

Machine is a System76 Lemur, shop installed Ubuntu 16.04.

Comment: I guess the problem might be with keyboard or terminal settings. Also, You can reinstall vim and try again.